# CSS/HTML Bootstrap 4 footer - on hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get a color change on hover in a Bootstrap footer. I can't seem to figure out the code to access the link properly.

Here is the pertinent part of my HTML:

```
<footer>
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <!-- <h4>ABOUT US</h4> -->
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/public/about/"><h5>ABOUT US</h5></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h5><strong>CONTACT INFO:</strong></h5><br>
                    <p><strong>Email:</strong> michael@hcmn.net</p>
                    <p><strong>Phone:</strong> (713)555-5555</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container2">
            <p><strong>© 2019 Ad Astra Web Services</strong></p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

It is the "ABOUT US" that I would like to change color on mouse hover.

Here is the current CSS code:

```
.container1 .nav-link a:hover {
color: #808080;
}
```

I believe it's just a matter of using the correct code to access the link.

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS selector is wrong. It should be:

```
.container1 .nav-link:hover {
   color: #808080;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/htf3EhitRj

Using `.nav-link a` means select the `a` that is a child of `.nav-item` which is not what you want.

Comment: Hmm... I did exactly as you said and it looks great in the CODEPLY you sent. However, I cannot get it to work. I tried a hard refresh to make sure the old CSS wasn't cached. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To change try this make little change to the css

```
.container1 a.nav-link:hover {
color: #808080;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah still not there. Actually I think I need to edit my code to make them list items anyways as I am adding a couple more links to the footer...

Comment: To remove the underline add text-decoration: none to your css

Comment: .container1 a.nav-link:hover {
    color: #808080;
    text-decoration: none;
}

Comment: Mohamed: Did you see my changes above? I made it into an <ul>. They are not called nav-links anymore. To differentiate from the top navbar I'm calling them "footer-links". My HTML has not changed from above and here is my current CSS. Still not working:

Comment: .container1 a.footer-links:hover {
 color: #808080;
 text-decoration: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
.col-md-3 a:hover {
  color: #808080;
 }
```

The code in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/bootstrap)